# Reversing the lines of a file

Tags: java, array, file

I am trying to reverse the lines of a file by reading the file through an array.

Is there a more efficient and quicker way of achieving this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class ReverseNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(file);

        int numoflines = 0;
        while(Scan.hasNextLine()) {
            Scan.nextLine();
            numoflines++;
        }
        Scan.close();
        Scan = new Scanner(file);

        int buffer[] = new int[numoflines]; //size

        for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = Scan.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i=buffer.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            int reverse = buffer[i];
            System.out.println(reverse);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The posted code does the following:

1. Read all lines, just for counting
2. Create an array with the right size
3. Read all lines *again*, this time for storing
4. Print all lines in reverse order

It's wasteful to read a file completely just to find the number of lines, and then need to read the file again to store the content.
It would be better to store the lines in a data structure that can grow its capacity as needed, to eliminate the need to know the number of lines in advance. That is, use any `List` implementation.

#### Possible bug

The description doesn't mention that there is precisely one integer per line in the input.
It must be the case, otherwise this code may not work well:

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
>     buffer[i] = Scan.nextInt();
> }
> ```

That is, if there are multiple numbers per line, then you will not read the entire file,
only the first \$N\$ numbers.
Similarly, if there are empty lines, then there may not be enough numbers,
and then the `.nextInt` call will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

The thing is, since there program doesn't use any integer operation,
only read and print,
there's no point reading integers.
Keep in mind that when you read integers,
you also incur a parsing step.
It would make more sense to read the lines as strings,
it would be simpler, and it seems that's all you really need anyway.

#### Suggested implementation

Here's an alternative, more efficient solution,
that also simplifies the reversing logic using a `LinkedList`, with a `descendingIterator`:

```
LinkedList<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
}
scanner.close();

Iterator<String> iterator = lines.descendingIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`LinkedList.descendingIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#descendingIterator%28%29). Jumping to a specific index in a `LinkedList` could be O(_N_).

Comment: Ok maybe that's cleaner. I rewrote to use your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
class ReverseNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL url = ReverseNumbers.class.getResource("/numbers.txt");

        List<String> values = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(url.getPath()));
        Collections.reverse(values);

        for(String s : values) {
            System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(s));
        }
    }
}
```

In terms of code, the above is, obviously, much more readable and basically uses the NIO classes for efficient management of file resources and Collections API for managing the list itself.

Also notice the getResource(String) can be a better way of loading resources as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861989/preferred-way-of-loading-resources-in-java).

There is also a [nice discussion](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things2/) on features of using Collections API over arrays.

I suppose Scanner is good if you are expecting different types of input in your file. Considering the fact that the file is called "numbers.txt" then you can do everything in a single read and manage the resulting collection in whichever way you want, rather than having to scan the file.

Comment: what do you mean by _would much rather use SLF4J_? What does this mean? This doesn't make any sense. Also reversing the collection is unnecessarily expensive, you should just loop backwards.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What I meant was that Considering he wishes to print the collection reversed it would be easier to do it in one call using SLF4J: `logger.info("{}", values)` (which will call toString() on the collection) than having to iterate through the list of values. You can get more information on SLF4J [here](http://www.slf4j.org/).

Comment: I know what SLF4J is! It's a logging library, you know. For logging. It should not be used for formatted output. If the file needs to be output to the console in reverse, `System.out` is the correct approach. A logging library adds all sorts of other things, timestamps. Code locations. Etc.

Comment: Also - what makes you think the OP's file is on the classpath?

Answer (score 3):

Taking all the points in [Janos' answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/81993/22486) and converting to Java 8 you have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("numbers.txt"))) {
        lines.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
                .descendingIterator()
                .forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

You still need the intermediate collection, as you cannot reverse a `Stream` without consuming it all.

This solution does loose the the `Scanner` though, which is known to be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the array isn't something you *have* to use, the natural solution to this kind of problem is to use a [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).  A stack is a data structure that is Last-In, First-Out.

The idea is that you read the file, one item(number, in your case) at a time, and 'push' each item on to the stack.  Once you've read all of the items, you 'pop' them off the stack to display them.

Here's an example of how to do it with a stack:

```
Stack<Integer> numbers = new Stack<Integer>();
File file = new File("numbers.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

while(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
    Integer next = scanner.nextInt();
    numbers.push(next);
}

while(!numbers.empty())
{
    Integer top = numbers.pop();
    System.out.print(reverse + " ");
}
```

A few notes:

- The reason the stack is declared as `Stack<Integer>` instead of `Stack<int>` is because int is a primitive type, which means it doesn't inherit from `Object`.  `Integer` does inherit from `Object`, so we use that instead.  There's a bit of a rabbit hole there but I won't delve deeper.  Other primitive types in Java(boolean, double, float, etc) have an analogous Object type(Boolean, Double, Float, etc).
- `Pop` is kind of tricky.  It's doing two things: it is returning the object on top of the stack, *and* it is removing that object from the stack.  Since it removes an element from the stack, `while(!numbers.empty())` will eventually be false and our loop will have run its course.

The downside to this approach is that you no longer have your numbers after the fact, since the `pop` functionality throws your numbers away.  There are still ways to get around this, but that's something you have to keep in mind.